# Android: ListView and TabWidget: The ListView goes over the TabWidget

Tags: android, android-listview, android-xml, tabwidget, android-tabs

I am using the TabWidget in my android project and I have a listView and a FrameLayout in the view. The problem is that when the ListView is higher than the screen height, the Tabs are invisible because the listview goes over the tabs.

I don't know how to set the listView above the tabs.

Here is my view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:minHeight="44dp" >

    </FrameLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/NewsCategorieslistView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/frameLayout"
        >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my tab view:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:divider="@null" >

    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        >
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: i was facing same issue problem was in my tab.xml can you post that.

Comment: Thank you @android-xx, I will do it immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
             android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs" />

        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this for your **tab.xml**( tab activity's layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: Thank you again @android-xx, I uploaded the rightxml now. I tryed your example and it works fine, except that the tab is on the top and I would like to have it on the bottom of the page and without margins. Could you help me please.

Comment: Thanks @android-xx, I have found the solution and posted the answer. Thank you very much for your help.